# What can cause unexpected tkinter widget resizing after frame resize?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, resize

One thing that can do it is assigning weights to non existent columns and rows. Maybe users know of others?

I recently had to track down this problem, and place it here in the hope it will be useful to others.
After resizing your window frame, tkinter will not resize widgets if you have assigned a non zero weight to non existent columns. I ran into this situation where I had a dynamic UI which hid a panel, and replaced it with some buttons. For these buttons to resize properly, I did a columnconfigure and assigned weights of 1 to these extra columns. When the UI was restored, these buttons were removed, and we went back to one column. However the weights for these non existent columns still influenced the resizing as seen in the attached figure.

[image: after resizing the window frame, we don't want to see the pink]

To solve the problem I reset the weights of these extra columns that I had set to 1 back to zero (even though these columns did not exist in the UI any more).

Minimal code to illustrate the problem is shown below:

The problem line is labelled `# @@@@@@@ this is a problem`

```
import tkinter as tk

class frame_resize:

    def setupGUI(self):
        self._root = tk.Tk()

        self._font = 'helvetica 16'

        self._mainFrame = tk.Frame(self._root, bg='pink')


        self._label = tk.Label(self._mainFrame, 
            font=self._font,
            bg='sky blue',
            text='this is some text')

        self._mainButton = tk.Button(self._mainFrame, text='Press here',
                              font=self._font)

        # give weights so that widgets expand when outer frame expands
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self._root, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self._root, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self._mainFrame, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self._mainFrame, 0, weight=1)


        # @@@@@@@ this is a problem, if we have no column 1
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self._mainFrame, 1, weight=1)

        #pop elemnts into grid
        self._mainFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        self._label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        self._mainButton.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nsew')

        self._root.mainloop()


fr = frame_resize()
fr.setupGUI()
```

Comment: _"After resizing your window frame, tkinter will fail to resize widgets if you have assigned a non zero weight to non existent columns."_ - that's not true. Tkinter doesn't fail in this case, it simply doesn't do what you might expect. However, it's behaving exactly as it's documented to behave.

Comment: Please format in the form of a question, and then post the solution as an answer. The question section is for questions, and this is not a question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do have a suggestion as to how better present the matter in the form of a question?  I think that tkinter behavior in this case is counter intuitive. Why give a weight to non existent columns? I think a more sensible behavior would be to check which rows or columns have any widgets in them and only assign weights to those rows/columns.

Comment: _"Why give a weight to non existent columns?"_ - there are several reasons. For example, if you give a weight to rows 0 and 2, and columns 0 and 2, and you put something in row 1, column 1, it will be centered because all extra space is allocated equally along the edges. Another reason would be to allocate all extra space to one side or another of a widget or group of widgets, or to add spacing between widgets. It's a very common technique.

Comment: OK Thanks for that. I had not come across that technique. I have edited my question to remove the word fail.